# How do I add a Macro programmatically to an Excel spreadsheet with Java

Tags: java, excel, vba

I use Apache-Poi to programmatically create an Excel spreadsheet, but it doesn't support adding macros.

Is there a way to add a macro to a spreadsheet with Java. Im happy to create the Macro manually within Excel if there was a way I could export it and then programmatically import/add it to a new spreadsheet but do not know if there is a way to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported programmatically. One way is to create excel with a template file. This can be done by Apache POI or JExcel library. You can open the doc, modify and save it as a new file using lib.

Apache POI clearly gives its [limitation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html) that macros can not be created.

Jexcel [link](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/) also gives that you can not create a macro but you can copy from a template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is available yet. Best solution for this is to create an empty workbook manually and code your Macro manually inside it then save this workbook as a template. Then whenever you need this Macro for your future workbooks, just use this existing workbook rather than starting a scratch workbook then you will find that your Macro is attached and enabled in this workbook as well. Hopefully this made sense!

Comment: Makes sense in principle, do you know how I use a template when creating spreadsheet inpoi

Comment: You'd just take the path to the existing template workbook you've set up (its like a placeholder) - So anytime you need this macro to be in a workbook you want to create, you build your spreadsheets into a copy of this workbook template. So instead of creating a fresh .xlsm file just grab the path to the existing workbook, Deal with the spreadsheet as needed, then save copy to a new location?

Comment: I mean in the context of creating spreadsheets with apache-poi, is that what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't tried it (tried similar things though, with some success). But you can give it a try: Looking at the `workbook.xml.rels` file inside the xlsm document, you can find the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" Target="styles.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme" Target="theme/theme1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet1.xml"/>
    <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/vbaProject" Target="vbaProject.bin"/>
</Relationships>
```

Pay attention to the last relation: that's the Macro file (**vbaProject**) 
So, you can extract the relations package and edit this particular XML, and add a new relation like the last one. Then, you have to package the Macro binary file into the `xl` directory, where the `styles.xml` and `workbook.xml` sit. I think that would do it.

For the first part, although you have methods in Apache POI like `document.getRelations()`, `RelationPart.addReation(...)`, and other similar methods, it seems to me they are intended to use with XML document parts, and that is not the case with macros. So, you can just use the Java ZipInputStream and ZipEntry util libraries, extract the XML file named workbook.xml.rels, build an XML document like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document xmlDoc = documentBuilder.parse(WORKBOOK.XML.RELS_INPUT_STREAM);
//INSERT HERE SOME LOGIC TO ADD THE DESIRED Relationship NODE

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result output = new StreamResult(SOME_OUTPUT_STREAM);
Source input = new DOMSource(xmlDoc);
transformer.transform(input, output);
```

And then manipulate the Zip file in oder to include the `vbaProject.bin` file you already have extracted from an actual Macro-enabled spreadsheet.

Would be nice to hear from your success!

Cheers

**EDIT**
You may also want to edit the [Content_Types].xml file to include the `bin` extension for the `vbaProject` content type, in case it's not already there:

```
<Default Extension="bin" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-office.vbaProject"/>
```

I think that's all.